# Проблема с таблицами html2pdf?

Tags: html

В библиотеке html2pdf делаю таблицу в таблице, и когда в ней ставлю `border: 1px solid black;`
получается вот такая вот штука:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и сам код:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
   <tr>
      <td style='width: 50%;'>
         <p style="text-align: center;">
            <img src='http://fasts-like.com/karkas/<?php echo $profilInfo[$i]['img']; ?>'>
          </p>
      </td>
      <td style='width: 50%;'>
         <table style="width: 100%;" >
             <tr>
                 <td style='width: 55%;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;'> 
                     <?php echo $profilInfo[$i]['name']; ?> А
                  </td>
                  <td style='width: 20%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
                     15 п/м.
                   </td>
                   <td style='width: 25%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
                     15 290 руб
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='width: 55%;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;'>
                      <?php echo $profilInfo[$i]['name']; ?> B
                   </td>
                   <td style='width: 20%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
                      30 п/м.
                   </td>
                   <td style='width: 25%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
                        40 290 руб
                   </td>
                 </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
```

А нужно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так у вас все получается так как и указываете. В чем проблема то? Как должно быть?

Comment: http://i12.pixs.ru/storage/8/3/6/Bezimyanni_5211481_23559836.png
Вот так вот нужно

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в  `border-collapse: collapse;` если я вопрос правильно поняла.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style='width: 50%;'>
      <p style="text-align: center;">
        <img src='http://fasts-like.com/karkas/<?php echo $profilInfo[$i]['img']; ?>'>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td style='width: 50%;'>
      <table style="width: 100%;" >
        <tr>
          <td style='width: 55%;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;'> 
            <?php echo $profilInfo[$i]['name']; ?> А
          </td>
          <td style='width: 20%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
            15 п/м.
          </td>
          <td style='width: 25%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
            15 290 руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style='width: 55%;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;'>
            <?php echo $profilInfo[$i]['name']; ?> B
          </td>
          <td style='width: 20%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
            30 п/м.
          </td>
          <td style='width: 25%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;'>
            40 290 руб
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Эта библиотека не поддерживает border-collapse: collapse;

Comment: ну так в стилях сами пропишите или и это не возможно?

Comment: Что именно прописать в стилях ?

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse;`

Вы же куда-то вставляете эту таблицу, стили там какие-то есть к этой странице

Comment: Библиотека html2pdf не поддерживает border-collapse: collapse; в стилях

Comment: я так понимаю ответа нет ?

Comment: а я так понимаю, что Вы и сами не знаете чего хотите.